problem with the origin when exporting the object
I am working with .glb files. Within blender if I change the origin of the object, export it and re-open it in blender everything seems to go as it should and this is retained. However, if I open the exported object within a python script with opencv all changes made to the origin are not saved. Is there a way to save the new origin of my object so that when I load it with python it is retained?

I don't think this is a problem with Blender or the Blender glTF exporter.  I'm certain Blender is writing the updated origin to the GLB file.  Perhaps OpenCV is re-centering the object, or not treating the origin the way you expect?  This question might be better on an OpenCV forum.
